# Vector of Structs --> Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, struct, linker-errors

While working on a C++ command line tool in Xcode, my executable was suddenly corrupted, the build failed, and I received an Apple Mach-O Linker Error. After a great deal of debug attempts, I narrowed the issue down to this section of code:

```
struct Word {
    std::string word;
    int syllCount, phoCount;
    std::vector<std::string> syllable, phoneme;
};

struct Unit {
    std::string str;
    std::vector<int> probs;
};
// **COMMENT OR RECEIVE ERROR HERE**
// std::vector<Word> words;
// std::vector<Unit> units;
```

Simply by deleting the two vector declarations out of the header file, all errors disappear; however, I need those vectors...

I've read up on the this particular error a bit, but nothing that I've found was caused in this fashion. Have I made an amateurish mistake, or is this an unusual error. Either way, any advice would be appreciated.

Here's the error message by the way:

```
duplicate symbol _words in:
>/Users/DASmithII/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Organizer->dviebpebgpvwotbsxuwyhrvulzfi/Build/Intermediates/Organizer.build/Debug/Organizer.build/Object>s-normal/x86_64/main.o
>/Users/DASmithII/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Organizer->dviebpebgpvwotbsxuwyhrvulzfi/Build/Intermediates/Organizer.build/Debug/Organizer.build/Object>s-normal/x86_64/Global.o
>duplicate symbol _units in:
>/Users/DASmithII/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Organizer->dviebpebgpvwotbsxuwyhrvulzfi/Build/Intermediates/Organizer.build/Debug/Organizer.build/Object>s-normal/x86_64/main.o
>/Users/DASmithII/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Organizer->dviebpebgpvwotbsxuwyhrvulzfi/Build/Intermediates/Organizer.build/Debug/Organizer.build/Object>s-normal/x86_64/Global.o
>ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Move the `std::vector<Word>` etc definitions to a .cpp file, and put `extern std::vector<Word>` etc in the header file.

Comment: You should put that as an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker is complaining that those symbols have been defined multiple times. This is because you have defined them in a header file which is included by more than one .cpp file, and so the compiler instantiates the objects multiple times.

Move the `std::vector<Word>` etc definitions to a .cpp file, and put `extern std::vector<Word>`etc in the header file, and the problem will go away.